# rxjs firstValueFrom() never unsubscribe the observavble

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, firebase, rxjs

Greatings,

I'm struggling with the firstValueFrom(), lastValueForm() and even Observable.pipe(take(1))...

I'm coding in type script with Angular 14 and RxJs 7.8.0.
My server is a firebase server which provide stored image url via an API with a getDownloadUrl function as an Observable.

What I want to do is download my url one time so I can display the image.

Whenever I try one of this method on my Observable it never unsubscribe so the Observable emit value infinitely.

I tried to write it with async/await syntax and also with the promise syntax but still not able to make it unsubscribe after the first emission.

I can't actually find any reason why it doesn't work...
Can some one help me ?

```
returnImage(ref: string){
  return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
    firstValueFrom(this.fireStorage.ref(ref).getDownloadURL()).then((url)=>{
      console.log(url);
    },(error)=>{
      reject(error);
    });
  });
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EllTn.png)

What I want to do is download my url one time so I can display the image.

Whenever I try one of this method on my Observable it never unsubscribe so the Observable emit value infinitely.

alreeady try to upgrade rxjs. I was using 7.5.0 but upgraded it to 7.8.0.

I tried to write it with async/await syntax and also with the promise syntax

Comment: reproduce the error using stackblitz so we can be better help for you.

Comment: Have you tried `const url = await firstValueFrom(this.fireStorage.ref(ref).getDownloadURL());`  ?

Comment: `firstValueFrom` itself returns a Promise but you're wrapping it again with `Promise` and then you nevel call `resolve`.

Comment: Where do you use `returnImage`?

Comment: @ShashanSooriyahetti I never used StackBlitz, but i'm gonna try so I can show you

Comment: @kellermat I tried it already but it still make the same result

Comment: @martin I saw that in documentation... but when i make a console.log() it never unsubscribe. So I've try many solutions as await/async, put it in a promise but it give me the same result

Comment: @Konrad The method you see is in a service. It's called from a component that have the service in constructor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thank you very much for your answers it helped me a lot.

1 _ @konrad put me on the way with his questions : I forgot to unsubscribe to my database observable which emit datasnapshot regularly.
I display data on my DOM from this observable and use a function to download image at the right time.
So I think the different syntaxes I tried were right but they were called many time by each datasnapshot emission...

2 _ @Shashan Sooriyahetti thanks to you... now I can use Stackblitz and by rewriting my method and testing it out of the whole system I created... I've been able to find my mistake.

So actually sorry for that guys and thank you very much for your help and reactivity.
Have nice coding time ;)